# Option to hide markers with using getZoom doesnt work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Does anyone could help me to understand why the option to hide markers with using getZoom doesnt work in my script?

I have updated the code by adding another solution that works and seems simpler

Part of code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(zoom >= 10);
    }
});
```

The all code:

```js
function round_down(n) {
    if (n > 0) {
      return Math.ceil(n / 0.05) * 0.05;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }

var map;
var pointCount = 0;
var locations = [];
var markers = [];
var gridWidth = 3660; // hex tile size in meters
var bounds;

var places = [
  [55.3, 14.8],
  [55.25, 14.85],
]

var SQRT3 = 1.73205080756887729352744634150587236;

$(document).ready(function(){
  
  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {center: {lat: 55.3, lng: 14.8}, zoom: 11});
  
  // Adding a marker just so we can visualize where the actual data points are.
  // In the end, we want to see the hex tile that contain them
  places.forEach(function(place, p){
    
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: place[0], lng: place[1]});
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng, 
  map: map})
  markers.push(marker);
  marker.addListener('click', set_window);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        markers[i].setVisible(zoom >= 10);
    }
});
    // Fitting to bounds so the map is zoomed to the right place
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  });
  
  
  
  // Now, we draw our hexagons! (or try to)
  locations = makeBins(places);
  
  locations.forEach(function(place, p){
    drawHorizontalHexagon(map, place, gridWidth);
  })
    
    
});

  
  function drawHorizontalHexagon(map, position, radius){
    var coordinates = [];
    for(var angle= 0;angle < 360; angle+=60) {
       coordinates.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, radius, angle));    
    }

    // Construct the polygon.
    var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coordinates,
        position: position,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        geodesic: true
    });
    polygon.setMap(map);
    polygon.addListener('click', set_window);
}

// Below is my attempt at porting binner.py to Javascript.
// Source: https://github.com/coryfoo/hexbins/blob/master/hexbin/binner.py

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2){
  console.log(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  result =  Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
  console.log("Distance: ", result);
  return
}

function nearestCenterPoint(value, scale){
    div = value / (scale/2);
    console.log("div", div);
    mod = value % (scale/2);
    console.log("mod", mod);
    
    if(div % 2 == 1){
      increment = 1;
    } else{
      increment = 0;
    }
    
    rounded = scale / 2 * (div + increment);
    
    if(div % 2 === 0){
      increment = 1;
    } else{
      increment = 0;
    }
    
    rounded_scaled = scale / 2 * (div + increment);
    
    result = [rounded, rounded_scaled]
    console.log("nearest centerpoint to", value, result);
    return result;
}

function makeBins(data){
  bins = [];
  
  data.forEach(function(place, p){
    x = place[0];
    y = place[1];
    
    console.log("Original location:", x, y);
    
    px_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(x, gridWidth);
    
    py_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(y, gridWidth * SQRT3);
    
    z1 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);
    z2 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);
    
    if(z1 > z2){
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: px_nearest[0], lng: py_nearest[0]});
       console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);
    } else {
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({lat: px_nearest[1], lng: py_nearest[1]});
       console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);
    }
  
    bins.push(bin);
    
  })
  return bins;
}
function set_window(event) {
    // Set Parameters
    var lat = event.latLng.lat();
    var lng = event.latLng.lng();
    var coord_slug = this.position.lat() + ', ' + (Math.round(this.position.lng() * 20) / 20);
alert(coord_slug);
}
```

```html
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.2.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h1>Hex Grid</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:80vh;">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Additional link: [The working part of the script in Plunger](http://plnkr.co/edit/nFMiDxS1XnqB0OcOFlla?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues with your code:

1. there is no (documented and useful) `.visible` property of a `google.maps.Marker`.  The documented way to change its visibility is with the `.setVisibility` method.
2. `marker` is a global variable, so once you have fixed the above, it only works on the last `marker`.  Need to define it inside the function with `var`.

Fixed code:

```
places.forEach(function(place, p) {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({
    lat: place[0],
    lng: place[1]
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map
  });
  markers.push(marker);
  marker.addListener('click', set_window);
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    zoom = map.getZoom();
    if (zoom < 10) {
      marker.setVisible(false);
    } else {
      marker.setVisible(true);
    }
  });
  // Fitting to bounds so the map is zoomed to the right place
  bounds.extend(latlng);
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/gfhaj9nq/4/)

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
function round_down(n) {
  if (n > 0) {
    return Math.ceil(n / 0.05) * 0.05;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

var map;
var pointCount = 0;
var locations = [];
var markers = [];
var gridWidth = 3660; // hex tile size in meters
var bounds;

var places = [
  [55.3, 14.8],
  [55.25, 14.85],
]

var SQRT3 = 1.73205080756887729352744634150587236;

$(document).ready(function() {

  bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
    center: {
      lat: 55.3,
      lng: 14.8
    },
    zoom: 11
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = map.getZoom();
  })

  // Adding a marker just so we can visualize where the actual data points are.
  // In the end, we want to see the hex tile that contain them
  places.forEach(function(place, p) {

    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng({
      lat: place[0],
      lng: place[1]
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map
    })
    markers.push(marker);
    marker.addListener('click', set_window);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function() {
      zoom = map.getZoom();
      if (zoom < 10) {
        marker.setVisible(false);
      } else {
        marker.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
    // Fitting to bounds so the map is zoomed to the right place
    bounds.extend(latlng);
  });

  // Now, we draw our hexagons! (or try to)
  locations = makeBins(places);
  locations.forEach(function(place, p) {
    drawHorizontalHexagon(map, place, gridWidth);
  })
});

function drawHorizontalHexagon(map, position, radius) {
  var coordinates = [];
  for (var angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 60) {
    coordinates.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(position, radius, angle));
  }

  // Construct the polygon.
  var polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: coordinates,
    position: position,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    geodesic: true
  });
  polygon.setMap(map);
  polygon.addListener('click', set_window);
}

// Below is my attempt at porting binner.py to Javascript.
// Source: https://github.com/coryfoo/hexbins/blob/master/hexbin/binner.py

function distance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  console.log(x1, y1, x2, y2);
  result = Math.sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2));
  console.log("Distance: ", result);
  return
}

function nearestCenterPoint(value, scale) {
  div = value / (scale / 2);
  console.log("div", div);
  mod = value % (scale / 2);
  console.log("mod", mod);

  if (div % 2 == 1) {
    increment = 1;
  } else {
    increment = 0;
  }

  rounded = scale / 2 * (div + increment);

  if (div % 2 === 0) {
    increment = 1;
  } else {
    increment = 0;
  }

  rounded_scaled = scale / 2 * (div + increment);

  result = [rounded, rounded_scaled]
  console.log("nearest centerpoint to", value, result);
  return result;
}

function makeBins(data) {
  bins = [];

  data.forEach(function(place, p) {
    x = place[0];
    y = place[1];

    console.log("Original location:", x, y);

    px_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(x, gridWidth);

    py_nearest = nearestCenterPoint(y, gridWidth * SQRT3);

    z1 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);
    z2 = distance(x, y, px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);

    if (z1 > z2) {
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({
        lat: px_nearest[0],
        lng: py_nearest[0]
      });
      console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[0], py_nearest[0]);
    } else {
      bin = new google.maps.LatLng({
        lat: px_nearest[1],
        lng: py_nearest[1]
      });
      console.log("Final location:", px_nearest[1], py_nearest[1]);
    }

    bins.push(bin);

  })
  return bins;
}

function set_window(event) {
  // Set Parameters
  var lat = event.latLng.lat();
  var lng = event.latLng.lng();
  var coord_slug = this.position.lat() + ', ' + (Math.round(this.position.lng() * 20) / 20);
  alert(coord_slug);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: white;
}

#map_canvas {
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry&key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="zoom"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I've updated the code by adding another solution that works and seems simpler. Thank you again for your help.